# How to add header when we writing test cases in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-testing

I'm trying to write test cases for my project. Now the problem is, that I don't figure out how to pass custom keyword arguments in the header. Here's my test case class below.

```
class ProjectTestClass(APITestCase,URLPatternsTestCase):

    allow_database_queries: True

    def projects_notifications_list(self,token,project_key):
        url = reverse('projects:project_noti_list',kwargs={"category": "all"})
        response = self.client.get(
            url,
            format='json', 
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION="JWT "+token,
            headers={"platform-subscriber-id":project_key}
            )
        print("data -> ",response.data)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.data), 3)
```

as you can see I'm passing plaform-subsciber-id in the header. but getting an error that  **{'message': 'Platform subscriber id is required in header'}**. It seems like id is not properly configured in the header. Does anybody know this?

Answer (score 7):

This is how you update headers in tests:

`headers = {'platform-subscriber-id': project_key}`

`self.client.credentials(**headers)`

DRF docs say: `The credentials method can be used to set headers that will then be included on all subsequent requests by the test client.`